# Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function in console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I using below code for reading file from my local system:

```
var fs = require('fs');            
var text = fs.readFileSync("./men.text");
var textByLine = text.split("\n")
console.log(textByLine);
```

Comment: What is `fs`? Forgot to import?

Comment: sorry.. i have also imported in file but forgot to write here.                          var fs = require("fs");

Comment: Are you trying to run the code in a browser?

Comment: yes. google-chrome

Comment: You can't run server-side code (like `fs`) in a browser.

Comment: @robertklep  then what we to do for the same requirements ?. We need to be read the file content from my local system and store in array or map(key, value).

Comment: @HimanshuPandey take a look [at this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser).

Comment: @robertklep  got it thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*NOTE:* *`fs`* is a nodejs module, you cannot use it in Browser.

Import the fs module,

`readFileSync` will provide you the Buffer

to use the `split()` function you have to convert the `Buffer` into `String`

```
var fs = require('fs')

var text = fs.readFileSync("./men.text");
var string = text.toString('utf-8') // converting the Buffer into String

var textByLine = string.split("\n")
console.log(textByLine);
```

---

▼ **UPDATE** ▼

---

Server-Side

`fs` is a nodejs built-in module, you cannot use it in Browser(Client-Side). Use `fs` in server-side to do the manipulation, get the data and format in required type, then you can `render` it with `html`, `ejs` many more.. templating engines

Here i have created a Nodejs Server using express, and from the browser hit the `http://localhost:8000/` you will get the Array of Data

You can format your data and render it with the `.ejs` or `html` files using `res.render`

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs')

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  var text = fs.readFileSync("./men.text");
  var string = text.toString('utf-8')

  var textByLine = string.split("\n")
  console.log(textByLine);
  response.send(textByLine);
});

app.listen('8000');
```

---

Dummy Output:

[image]

Comment: still getting same error  **Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function **

Comment: did you save the file, are you running the code in browser,

Comment: Node.js runs on the server, `fs` is a nodejs module, if you want to load the text file in browser, then you can render it using html, ejs from express routes or can use AJAX request to hit them

Comment: please look at mine updated answer, i'd only send the data, but you can use the html, ejs files to send the data along with html, ejs , where you have to set the view engine, static files path, on the server

Answer (score 2):

To all who are still getting undefined function on there eletron apps :

The solution  (at least for me) was to instead of doing :

`const fs = require('fs');`

I did :

`const fs = window.require('fs');`

And that fixed ALL the problemes I had.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var text = fs.readFileSync('./men.text', 'utf8');
var textByLine = text.split("\n");
console.log(textByLine);
```